# How can I send an iCalendar email attachment with Django?

Tags: python, django, icalendar

I want to send an iCalendar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar email attachment using Django.  Is there an open source library to build an iCalendar file in Python and/or available for Django?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated before, there is [vobject](http://vobject.skyhouseconsulting.com/), that is working fine (I have used it recently).

You can find good information about ical, vobject and django in this blog post :

http://blog.thescoop.org/archives/2007/07/31/django-ical-and-vobject/

Comment: BTW, since this answer, I wrote a blog post about this question: http://www.multitasked.net/2010/jun/16/exporting-schedule-django-application-google-calen/

Comment: The link is no longer valid - any other links that show Django email sending with an iCalendar attachment?

Answer (score 4):

I've used MaxM's [icalendar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/icalendar/) module. It can build and parse iCalendar files.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [vobject](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/vobject/) which was developed for the Chandler project and seems to be more actively maintained.  It's also BSD-licensed which might be important for your use case.